# How do I use runit to manage my custom made node.js service?

Tags: autorun

My service is very basic, just an HTTP service. I just want it to restart automatically when it quits because of an error. I figured I could use runit to do this, but it seems like the runit docs mostly talk about how to convert your entire init.d to runit. I want to preserve init.d and just use runit for my one service.

I was looking at these [docs](http://smarden.org/runit/).

Thanks.

EDIT: I think [this](http://smarden.org/runit/useinit.html) is pointing in the right direction, I guess I just need to know how to make a service now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node is really simple to get running with runit. Assuming you already have runit installed in a standard directory layout, create the directory `/service/node-service` and place the create the file `/service/node-service/run`:

```
#!/bin/sh
chpst -unobody node /path/to/your-service.js
```

Make that run script executable (chmod +x run) and you can test it by running sudo ./run. If you're running on Debian or Ubuntu, rather than installing runit from source it's easiest to just `apt-get install runit` and create the directory `/etc/sv/node-service` instead of `/service/node-service`, and then symlink `/etc/sv/node-service` to `/etc/service/node-service`. Also, if you want your service to run in the context of a user other than nobody, you should change the `-u<username>` parameter to reflect that.

Comment: This actually answers the question so I'm marking this as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [forever](https://github.com/indexzero/forever).